# Проблема с [WinError 32] при работе с файлами

Tags: python-3.x

Делаю скрипт, который будет сортировать мои загрузки.
Он нормально переносит фотографии (jpg, png), но когда я пытаюсь перенести `html` или `rar` файл, то появляется ошибка:

```
Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'D:/Downloads/HW.rar' -> 'D:/DownloadsSorted/Archives/HW.rar'
```

Каким образом можно решить?

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import time

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            extension = filename.split('.')
            if len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'jpg' or extension[1].lower() == 'png' or extension[1].lower() == 'svg'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Images/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and extension[1].lower() == 'html':
                print()
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/HTMLfiles/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'mp4' or extension[1].lower() == 'pcm' or extension[1].lower() == 'wav'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Music/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'ppt' or extension[1].lower() == 'pptjpeg' or extension[1].lower() == 'pptpng' or extension[1].lower() == 'pptx'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/PowerPoint/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'py'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/PyFiles/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'sql'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/SQLfiles/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'torrent'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Torrent/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'avi' or extension[1].lower() == 'm4v' or extension[1].lower() == 'flv'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Videos/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'docx' or extension[1].lower() == 'doc' or extension[1].lower() == 'docm'):

                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Word/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            elif len(extension) > 1 and (extension[1].lower() == 'rar' or extension[1].lower() == 'zip' or extension[1].lower() == '7zip'):
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Archives/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)

            else:
                file = folder + '/' + filename
                new_path = folder_new + '/Else/' + filename
                os.rename(file, new_path)


folder = 'D:/Downloads'
folder_new = 'D:/DownloadsSorted'

handle = Handler()
obserser = Observer()
obserser.schedule(handle, folder, recursive=True)
obserser.start()

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    obserser.stop()

obserser.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, добавив в начало цикла:

```
def on_modified(self, event):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            extension = filename.split('.')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue

        if extension[1] == 'tmp':
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
```